# Xcode MVC Issue - Need a multi Model - single View

Tags: xcode, macos, model-view-controller

I've recently started working with Xcode, having come from a C# background. I'm struggling to implement something for OSX that I'd find fairly trivial in C#.

Basically, I want to create a model that contains, say, two points. I then want to open a window which contains a Custom View that is linked to an object that is a subclass of NSView. I then want to draw a line between those two points using the dirtyRect function of my NSView based object.

I've followed examples for this & it works fine. However, I want to be able to open a number of windows, each of the same type of view so the data is displayed using the same technique, but having each one associated with a different model.

How can I let my NSView based object know what model data it should be drawing? I assume I'm missing something stupidly simple here...

Thanks,

Tom.